# Can a subclass have an association with its parent class?

Tags: java, oop

We are asked to find if its possible to have a subclass that has an association with its parent class, and if it does has sense.

I made my own example like:

```
class CompanyPerson{}

class Boss extends CompanyPerson{}

class Employee extends CompanyPerson{
    CompanyPerson boss;
}
```

I understand that this works, I also tried on Eclipse, and indeed, it works. But what I don't understand, is why should i want this kind of association instead of having a Boss attribute in my Employee class.

Surely because I don't have a wide perspective about object oriented programming, but in this case, I can't see the point on it.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of associating 'CompanyPerson' instead of 'Boss' is that if you ever introduce a third type of CompanyPerson (ex. Manager), you will be able to assign it as your boss without changing a single line of your existing code.

It is a good practice to always have your code open for extension. In that regard, you can have a brief reading of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles

Comment: Thanks, I was focusing on the example, but it's true that if I have more classes as you say it could be useful to leave them less restrictive. I will check also the SOLID principles for a better understanding of oop.

Comment: You don't always want your class to be extensible. Joshua Bloch advises "Design for inheritance or else prohibit it." (_Effective Java_) I'm of the school of thought that one should prefer "prohibit it".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are perfectly right: A variable of type `Boss` is much more meaningful in this particular example. I'd just call it `Supervisor`, to better express the relation between the two, but that's beside the point right now.

However, I think the contract you were asked for is a little weirdly worded. The misunderstanding might reside in the word association. As you correctly guessed, an association is built in between instances of classes, but the contract explicitly asks for an association between a child and a parent class.

So what you are actually looking for is an association between the child and the parent class on the same instance. In other words, if there is an instance of type `Employee` does it have an association to itself as type `CompanyPerson`?.